# SQL Server delete trigger - row handle referred to a deleted row or a row marked for deletion

Tags: sql-server, triggers

I have a delete trigger on a table which is used to delete entries from a table in an another database.

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[Trigger_Contracts_Delete] ON [dbo].[Contracts]
AFTER DELETE NOT FOR REPLICATION
AS
  IF @@ROWCOUNT = 0 RETURN

  DELETE seconddb.dbo.second_table 
  WHERE contractId IN (SELECT d.ContractID FROM deleted d)
```

When I delete a record using my application (legacy app nothing know about its internals)  I get the error "Row handle referred to a deleted row or a row marked for deletion"

However when I modified this trigger to add an additional select statement (`SELECT d.ContractID FROM deleted d`) just before delete.. I do not get the error message. What could be the reason for it to work when select statement is added, is it that by issuing select on "deleted" I have locked the "deleted" table ?
it be issuing a

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[Trigger_Contracts_Delete] ON [dbo].[Contracts]
AFTER DELETE NOT FOR REPLICATION
AS
   IF @@ROWCOUNT = 0 RETURN

   SELECT d.ContractID FROM deleted d;

   DELETE seconddb.dbo.second_table 
   WHERE contractId IN (SELECT d.ContractID FROM deleted d)
```

Comment: Is there a trigger on the seconddb.dbo.secondtable.   In general, this error occurs when trying to reference a row from a table in the middle of a uncommitted transaction.   Just for a thought, try adding a NOLOCK hint to the  IN (SELECT d.ContractID FROM deleted d)

Comment: Thanks Sparky. Here are more details 
seconddb.dbo.second_table has a child table seconddb.dbo.second_table_child which has cascaded delete relationship [if parent record in seconddb.dbo.second_table is deleted children records in seconddb.dbo.second_table_child will be deleted. ]. And there is a delete trigger on seconddb.dbo.second_table_child which is used to update parent record in seconddb.dbo.second_table  when a row from seconddb.dbo.second_table_child is deleted.

Comment: Have you found a solution for this?

Answer (score 4):

your table(s) are missing primary keys!
add primary keys and the problem will go away.

Comment: I wish I had posted the findings at the time. Now I don't remember and don't have a way back track - job change.

Comment: Never experienced this myself but seems feasible according to http://robertoschiabel.wordpress.com/2008/10/20/row-handle-referred-to-a-deleted-row-or-a-row-marked-for-deletion/

Answer (score 0):

If you alawys want to delete the records from the child table, why not set up cascading delte instead of a trigger?

Comment: The tables are in different databases, so there is no foreign key. Therefore we used the Trigger.